# next_post_link on custom taxonomy

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

I want to use `next_post_link` and `prev_post_link` to return only the next post in my custom taxonomy of a custom post type. I have a custom post type called "work_posts" which has the taxonomy "work_categories" assigned. The category I want to show is called 'all'. I looked up `get_adjacent_post` in the "link-template.php" which has a few filters which should make it possible to make such a query but my SQL is not good enough to make the right query. The hooks are:

- `get_{$adjacent}_post_join`
- `get_{$adjacent}_post_where`
- `get_{$adjacent}_post_sort`

if I log a query in the join hook I get:

```
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships AS tr 
ON p.ID = tr.object_id 
INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy tt 
ON tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id 
AND tt.taxonomy = 'category' 
AND tt.term_id IN (3)
```

how do I modify this to only show posts from my custom taxonomy?

Comment: Why not use query_posts or wp_query ? What's the need for sql here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/ambrosite-nextprevious-post-link-plus/
Its a plugin that adds extra missing functionality to next_post_link and prev_post_link functions.

Comment: Hi בניית אתרים, thanks for your answer, worked perfect.

Answer (score 2):

I was with the same problem.

The correct plugin to be used to fix the problem is [this](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/previous-and-next-post-in-same-taxonomy/).

And it seems that a bug is already reported [here](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/17807).